# Why is the Registry Key showing null in C# even if it is present in Registry Editor?

Tags: c#, windows, registry, registrykey

Here is my c# code:

```
using (RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile",  true))
{
    key.CreateSubKey("NetworkThrottlingIndex");
    key.SetValue("NetworkThrottlingIndex", "0000000a", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    key.CreateSubKey("SystemResponsiveness");
    key.SetValue("SystemResponsiveness", "00000000", RegistryValueKind.DWord);
    key.CreateSubKey("NoLazyMode");
    key.SetValue("NoLazyMode", "1");
}
```

So what is happening here is that I am getting an error

> System.NullReferenceException

on the line

```
key.CreateSubKey("NetworkThrottlingIndex");
```

because the key is null.

I checked several times but this key is present in my registry editor.

Any idea about what is wrong here?

Comment: accesing LM needs admin rights ... from docks:  /OpenSubKey returns/ *The subkey requested, or **`null`** if the operation failed.* of course theoritically it should give `SecurityException` but maybe it doesn't ... try run app with admin rights

Comment: Yeah my app runs with administrator privileges. I have added that to app.manifest file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The SOFTWARE registry key is redirected](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/winprog64/shared-registry-keys?redirectedfrom=MSDN) depending on the bitness of your application and Windows.

To access your key via a x86/32bit EXE (on 64 bit Windows) request the 64 bit *Registry View*:

```
using (var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(RegistryHive.LocalMachine, RegistryView.Registry64))
using (var key = hklm.OpenSubKey(@"SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Multimedia\SystemProfile", RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree))
{
   ...
}
```

Also note that `NetworkThrottlingIndex` is a sub-key (i.e. a "*Folder*") and thus you cannot set its value as it has none. Additionally you would use hex literals for the DWORD values (`0x0000000a`) rather that strings.